# How to query elements in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I would like to query elements in my Shiny app based on their HTML tags. For the following app, for example, how do I access all `h1` elements including their label and id?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Get", id = "1"),
  h1("this", id = "2"),
  h2("But", id = "3"),
  h3("not", id = "4"),
  h4("that", id = "5")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: is your goal to access these elements from within the shiny app?

Comment: Yes. More specifically, from an R Markdown script that is rendered from within the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you tagged `javascript` in your question, find a solution based on shinyJS/JS.

You can use the following code to identify the `h1` elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
var sendToR = [];
for (var nr = 0; nr < elements.length; nr++) {
    var newElement = {};
    newElement['id'] = elements[nr].id;
    newElement['text'] = elements[nr].textContent;
    sendToR.push(newElement);
}
```

Then you can "send" the results to R via:

```
Shiny.onInputChange('h1', sendToR)
```

And receive on R side with:

```
observe({
    print(input$h1)
  })
```

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  h1("Get", id = "1"),
  h1("this", id = "2"),
  h2("But", id = "3"),
  h3("not", id = "4"),
  h4("that", id = "5")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    runjs("
      var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
      var sendToR = [];
      for (var nr = 0; nr < elements.length; nr++) {
          var newElement = {};
          newElement['id'] = elements[nr].id;
          newElement['text'] = elements[nr].textContent;
          sendToR.push(newElement);
      }
      Shiny.onInputChange('h1', sendToR)
    ")
  })

  observe({
    print(input$h1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```